# What version(s) of adjacent tools is(are) compatible with Spring XD?

Tags: spring-xd

Spring XD interacts with the following backing components:

- Zookeeper
- JDBC Datastore (MySql, Postgres, etc...)
- RabbitMQ, Redis, or Kafka (Transport)
- Redis (Analytics)

Is there any documentation on which versions of these technologies should be used when running Spring XD in Distributed Mode?

Presumably when new versions of Spring XD are released, the compatible versions of the adjacent technologies may change. Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I found a dependency list in the [build.gradle file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/build.gradle) in GitHub.  This is from the master:

```
ext {
  xdAdminUIVersion = '1.2.0.RELEASE'
  // Not in IO
  activemqVersion = '5.6.0'
  apacheFtpServerVersion = '1.0.6'
  args4jVersion = '2.0.16'
  curatorVersion = '2.6.0'
  equalsverifierVersion = '1.1.3'
  ftpServerVersion = '1.0.6'
  apacheSshdVersion = '0.10.1'
  greenmailVersion = '1.3.1b'
  httpClientVersion = '4.2.5'
  jcloudsVersion = '1.7.0'
  oracleToolsVersion = '1.2.2'
  platformVersion = '1.0.1.RELEASE'
  postgresqlVersion = '9.4-1201-jdbc41'
  splunkVersion = '1.3.0'
  springBatchAdminMgrVersion = '1.3.0.RELEASE'
  springIntegrationSplunkVersion = '1.1.0.RELEASE'
  springIntegrationKafkaVersion = '1.2.1.RELEASE'
  kafkaVersion = '0.8.2.1'
  springShellVersion = '1.1.0.RELEASE'
  zookeeperVersion = '3.4.6'
  sparkVersion = '1.2.1'
  sparkScalaVersion = '2.10'
  sqoopVersion = '1.4.5'

  // Also in IO
  nettyVersion = '3.7.0.Final' // N.B. Reactor depends on Netty 4
  hadoopGuavaVersion = '11.0.2' // This is only used by the mini cluster in the spring-xd-batch-extension tests
  cdh5GuavaVersion = '14.0.1' // This is only used by the CDH 5 module for the xd/lib/cdh5 classpath jars
  oldGuavaVersion = '15.0'  // This is only used by spring-xd-integration-test, IO uses version 17.0
  guavaVersion = '16.0.1'

  springDataHadoopBase = '2.2.0.RELEASE'

  //    //Reactor 1.1 is used in spring-xd-extension-batch transitively though spring integration
  //    reactor11xVersion = '1.1.5.RELEASE'

  singleNodeServerProcess = new SingleNodeServerProcess()
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but not quite what I'm looking for.